# Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime number. For $n \ge 3$, prove that $p_{n+3}^2 \lt p_np_{n+1}p_{n+2}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime number.  For $n \ge 3$, prove that $p_{n+3}^2 \lt p_np_{n+1}p_{n+2}$.

The book gives a hint as $p^2_{n+3} \lt 4p_{n+2}^2 \lt 8p_{n+1}p_{n+2}$, but I don't understand how to show that the hint is true either.

The only inequality relationship with prime squares that I know is Bonse's inequality but I can't seem to derive either the hint or the main problem from this.

Comment: The hint employs Bertrand's postulate (also known as Chebyshev's theorem, since Chebyshev proved it), that there is always a prime between $x$ and $2x$ (for $x > 1$). Thus $p_{n+3} < 2p_{n+2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the hint, you just need to show $8< p_{n}$, which I think you got (if you can't quite assume $8< p_n$ then think about proving it for very small $n$ by just verifying the inequality works).  And proving the hint involves something about primes between $k$ and $2k$.

Comment: Then it seems the conjecture is false unless the condition $n \ge 3$ is changed to $n \ge 5$ since $p_n \lt 8$ for $n \le 4$?

Comment: Check it by hand for small $n$.  Just plug the values into the formula and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=3$, show it manually:

$(p_{n+3})^2=(p_{6})^2=13^2=169<385=5\cdot7\cdot11=(p_{3})(p_{4})(p_{5})=(p_{n})(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})$

---

For $n=4$, show it manually:

$(p_{n+3})^2=(p_{7})^2=17^2=289<1001=7\cdot11\cdot13=(p_{4})(p_{5})(p_{6})=(p_{n})(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})$

---

For $n\geq5$, use the fact that $p_{n+1}<2p_{n}$:

$(p_{n+3})^2<$

$(2p_{n+2})^2=$

$4(p_{n+2})(p_{n+2})<$

$4(2p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})=$

$8(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})<$

$11(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})=$

$(p_{5})(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})\leq$

$(p_{n})(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})$